# How to configure an IOPS type EBS after attachment on Amazon AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, provisioned-iops

Once I have created an EBS of IOPS type and attached to an EC2 volume, is there a way to change its settings such as storage and IOPS? I am fine detaching it and making changes. Obviously I want to retain data.

[image]

I am looking for an answer preferably on the AWS Console but even a command line approach is welcome.

I am using Windows AMI.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't change the EBS size and IOPS once it's attached to EC2 and it's a running instance. You'll need to stop it to make any changes.

First, shutdown your instance.

In the snapshots menu option - select the volume you want to change and make a snapshot. Once the snapshot is created, you right click on it and select "Create Volume" then select your size and type.

On your old Volume select it, right click and select the Detach option. Then find the snapshot you created and attach it.

Then start your instance again.

Comment: Somewhat correct, but there is no need to shutdown the instance.  Just snapshot it, wait to complete, unmount/detach original volume, then reattach the new one/remount.

Comment: What @skrewler said, with a note that you may need to run fsck or otherwise fix filesystem integrity if you leave the FS attached while making a snapshot.  Filesystem integrity has yet to prove an issue for me.

Comment: This is an outdated answer. You no longer need to stop/start or attach/detach.

Answer (score 15):

AWS recently announced [Elastic Volumes](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/02/amazon-elastic-block-store-amazon-ebs-enables-live-volume-modifications-with-elastic-volumes/?sc_channel=em&sc_campaign=Launch_RN20170221_c&sc_publisher=aws&sc_medium=em_31632&sc_content=launch_la_nontier1&sc_country=IL&sc_geo=&sc_category=mult&sc_outcome=launch&mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiTnpoaVpXTmhaRFJpTnpJeiIsInQiOiJSTitCWUN5cXdIY1hxRWlNUklYTXo5MVBUWkhuQUVCV082VU4wMWFZWkh3TDZyUEdaNFpaRmZMMTdmK0o4aGFPazVFemNyVWRcL25HV0JvNkVmYnU5WmpQQW1zUXVic3BrZm9tWDVpam56a1wvalA5YXViT2MxVHJweThIMFdRN0wxIn0%3D), which make it possible to modify the volume type (SSD/HDD/PIOPS), volume size (GB), and provisioned IOPS of EBS volumes with no downtime or performance impact.

All EBS volumes have been converted into Elastic Volumes as of today, so this functionality is already available in your AWS account!

**Simply right click the EBS volume -> Modify and enter a new IOPS value.**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can modify your EBS Volume without any downtime.

[image: Go to volume via instance]

[image: Select volume then click right and change and choose modify.]